# IE won't submit dynamically added form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I have a problem in IE later than 7, 8 and 9 both give me this problem. But IE 7 and all other browsers don't notice.

In my form I dynamically clone the first `DIV` I have, this gives me a new div with the fields cloned, the fields are field arrays like so `name="myfield[]"`.

When I submit in IE 8 and 9 it just returns it as if only one element was in the array and not the many I cloned.

This is the full form HTML and JS:

```
<p><strong>Choose the number of certificates you would like:</strong></p>
<label><input name="type" value="1" checked="checked" type="radio" onclick="oneCert();" checked /> $25 for one (1) certificate</label><br>
<label><input name="type" value="3" type="radio" onclick="threeCerts();" /> $50 for three (3) certificates</label><br>
<label><input name="type" value="5" type="radio" onclick="fiveCerts();" /> $75 for five (5) certificates</label>
<br><br>
<p>A personal message for each selection is optional and must be 20 words or less.</p>
<p><i>If you would like to purchase more than five (5) certificates, please select the $75 for five (5) certificates option and you will be able to add two (2) certificates for $25.</i></p>
<div id="mainForm">

<div id="people" style="border: 2px solid #000; padding: 10px; margin: 5px;">
Please enter Teacher or Staff Member’s First and Last Name:<br />
First and Last Name of Person: <input name="person[]" value="" style="margin: 5px;" type="text" /><br />
<div class="error-message-person"></div>
Teacher/Staff School: <input name="school[]" value="" style="margin: 5px;" type="text" /><br />
<div class="error-message-school"></div>
Student's Full Name: <input name="student[]" value="" style="margin: 5px;" type="text" /><br />
<div class="error-message-student"></div>
Parent(s) Full Name(s): <input name="parents[]" value="" style="margin: 5px;" type="text" /><br />
<div class="error-message-parents"></div>
Personal message to teacher or staff member:<br />
<textarea name="pmes[]" cols="40" rows="3" maxlength="200"></textarea><br />
</div>

</div>

<input value="Order Now" type="submit" />

<script>
function cloner () {
  jQuery('#people').clone().appendTo('#mainForm').attr('class', 'people').removeAttr('id');
  jQuery('.people:last').children('input[name="person[]"]').val('').parent()
                        .children('input[name="student[]"]').val('').parent()
                        .children('input[name="school[]"]').val('').parent()
                        .children('input[name="parents[]"]').val('');
  jQuery('#mainForm').html(jQuery('#mainForm').html());
}

function addInd () {
  jQuery('#mytext').remove();

  cloner();
  cloner();

  jQuery('#mainForm').append('<div id="mytext">Need more? Add 2 more for $25 by clicking <a href="#" onclick="addInd(); return false;">here</a>.</div>');
}

function threeCerts () {
  while(jQuery('.people').length < 2) {
    cloner();
  }

  while(jQuery('.people').length > 2) {
    jQuery('.people:last').remove();
  }

  jQuery('#mytext').remove();
}

function fiveCerts () {
  while(jQuery('.people').length < 4) {
    cloner();
  }

  while(jQuery('.people').length > 4) {
    jQuery('.people:last').remove();
  }

  jQuery('#mytext').remove();
  jQuery('#mainForm').append('<div id="mytext">Need more? Add 2 more for $25 by clicking <a href="#" onclick="addInd(); return false;">here</a>.</div>');
  jQuery('.people:last div').css('display', 'block');
}

function oneCert () {
  if(jQuery('.people').length > 1) {
    jQuery('.people').each(function(index) {
      this.remove();
    });
  }

  jQuery('#mytext').remove();
}

</script>
```

As you can see I've tried making IE notice the DOM refresh using the `html()` command to change the `innerHTML` from itself to itself, but that doesn't work either. This `html()` trick worked for me in getting IE7 to work, but still IE 9 and 8 won't accept dynamically added, or in this case cloned, fields to the form.

I've also tried changing the `html()` call from the DIV ID to the Form ID but still no go.

I've also tried calling an `alert()` on the `onSubmit` of the button and also on the `cloner()` function, thinking this might force IE to refresh the DOM. But also doesn't work.

The array always returned in IE 8 and 9 is:

```
Array ( [type] => 3 [person] => Array ( [0] => ) [school] => Array ( [0] => ) [student] => Array ( [0] => ) [parents] => Array ( [0] => ) [pmes] => Array ( [0] => ) [04a9ffd12221f8353baf957d190ee2e6] => 1 )
```

No matter what I select, in theory if I select option 2 or 3 I should get more in each array, it works fine in IE 7 and Chrome, Opera, FF, etc.

Comment: try to use `name='inputname[]'` just put `[]` after the name

Comment: does page pass w3C validation?

Comment: Where is the code for the actual form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much back and forth with JS code and adding new elements then re-doing the `innerHTML` I found the only solution that I think there was. Seems this problem continues no matter what I did in IE 7 thru 9. But fixing it was only possible using a new form created dynamically in JS then appending that newly created form to the Body at the end then submitting. Not sure about IE in Windows 8, hadn't gotten that far to test yet, but should work there also.

Kind of a hack to get it done and don't like a fully dynamic hidden form, but it seems to work flawlessly in the aforementioned IE's.

First off get the IE version using JS and store into a variable:

```
var ie = (function(){

    var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        all[0]
    );

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());
```

Then we need to itterate through the entire form and clone each element into our newly created form then append:

```
function subber () {
    if(ie >= 7) {
      var postto = jQuery('#chronoform_PATS').attr("action");
      var form = document.createElement("form")
      jQuery(form).attr("id", "patsform").attr("name", "patsform").attr("action", postto).attr("method", "post");

      jQuery('input:text').each(function() {
          jQuery(form).append(jQuery(this).clone());
      });

      jQuery('textarea').each(function() {
          jQuery(form).append(jQuery(this).clone());
      });

      jQuery('input:radio').each(function() {
          jQuery(form).append(jQuery(this).clone());
      });

      document.body.appendChild(form);
      form.submit();
      document.body.removeChild(form);

      return false;
    } else { jQuery('#chronoform_PATS').submit(); }
}
```

Of course if your not inside an IE browser it just submits, other wise it creates the new form, then clones all elements found to that form, appends then submits. Lastly it removes that form and returns false to keep the previous form from submitting.

The button element is the following:

```
<input value="Order Now" type="submit" onclick="subber(); return false;" />
```